# Specifiyng changes in the checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with linking ticks in checkboxes to values in other list and making formatting based on this afterwards.

*(i. e. person clicks the checkbox and the cell turns grey)*

So, I have a number of check boxes, each text box is labeled as

"Check Box 1"
...
"Check Box 44"

```
    Sub Link()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim checkbox(1 To 44) As checkbox

    For i = 1 To 44
        For Each element In checkbox
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(element)).Select
            With Selection
            .Value = xlOn
            .LinkedCell = "Calculation!$A$" & "i"
            .Display3DShading = False
            End With
        Next
    Next

    End Sub
```

But it seems I am either selecting checkboxes wrong, or either assign their array in a wrong way. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You link to`Calculation!$A$i`, instead of `Calculation!$A$1`...`Calculation!$A$44`with`.LinkedCell = "Calculation!$A$" & i`. And avoid [Select/Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Are these checkboxes from the Forms controls menu?

Comment: I would use a checkboxes collection instead of an array. Also I think `checkbox()` should be declared as a variant. And btw it's a bad practice to use reserved names for your variables.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComputerVersteher has nailed your basic problem, but you can adopt a slightly simpler approach thus:

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count
    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(i)
        .Value = xlOn
        .LinkedCell = "Calculation!$A$" & i
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

This does assume the checkboxes are named in order (which by default they should be).

All that said, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do.